# IE11 crash on right mouse button click

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, crash

I have a web-based information system - where we have implemented a customized HTML grid.
When doing RMB click on a row, it returns a selection of action you can choose.
But for some reason on IE11 - When doing multiple RMB clicks without selecting any action it 45 to 60% of the time crashes with:

Though after additional research, the issues seems to be caused by some of the code. Though it is pretty standard code.

So I would very much appreciate if anyone has some knowledge/idea or etc of what or how this could be handled. 
Or how to narrow down what might cause the crash.

And it does not crash when Dev Tools are open
(Have tried tinkering with the disk space on IE)

Comment: You have answered your own question already: *"the issues seems to be caused by some of the code"*. Without more information, it's highly unlikely that someone will come up with a more concrete answer than that.

Comment: Did you received any error in dialog or in developer tools? Try to post the sample code that can produce the issue. We will try to test the issue and try to check for possible solution or any work around.